# Find the general solution of $y' \cot x +y =2$

Tags: differential

How do you start by finding the general solution? And then finding the integration constant using the initial condition $y(0)=1$

So far I've got...

$$y' \cot x +y = 2\\\frac{dy}{2}-y = \tan x dx\\\int \frac{dy}{2}-y = \int \tan x dx\\-\ln(2-y) =-\ln|\cos x| + C$$

Is this right and what are the next steps?

Comment: @Moo how do I simplify that, should i rearrange for y(x) ?

Comment: ok so i got c is = 0 using the IC how did you get the y(x) = 2 - cosx bit

Comment: Oh my bad sorry i understand now

Answer (score 1):

**Solving a Separable First Order ODE Using Initial Conditions**

Your solution looks right so far.

The next step would be to use the initial condition given,  `y(0) =1`. Which is translated to mean that when `x=0` then `y=1`. By substituting this into the general equation you have already found, the sole, remaining unknown `C` can be solved for. In this case it looks like `C=0`

**Edit**: After arriving at:
$-ln(2-y) = -ln|cos x| + C$

Taking the exponents on both sides will give:
$e^{ln(2-y)^{-1}} = e^{(ln|cos x|^{-1} + C)}$

Which, using the laws of exponents, can be written as:

$e^{ln(2-y)^{-1}} = e^Ce^{ln|cos x|^{-1}}$

And simplified to be:
$(2-y)^{-1}= e^C|cos x|^{-1}$

$\frac{1}{2-y}= e^C \frac{1}{|cos x|}$

$y = 2-\frac{ |cos x| }{e^C} $

Again,  as before,  using the initial condition given, $y(0) =1$ (that is $y=1$ when $x=0$) - we find that $C = 0$ or $e^C = 1$.

Comment: So my last line of working is the general solution? So i just did that and c does = 0 is that all i needed to do? What would the integration constant be?

Comment: Yes, your last line containing C is the general solution and that C is the integration constant.

Comment: Thankyou i was reading the question wrong!

Comment: shouldnt the general solution be y = ... or something like that?

Comment: Mathematically it would be the same. However, you are right in that conventionally the general solution is given in terms of y. (See edit)

Comment: thanks, ive just had a bit of trouble presenting it in terms of y, when i do that the value of c changes from 0

Comment: C should remain as 0. The edited version should be easier to follow.